# Decide which Window open in QT on start

Tags: c++, qt

I need help. I'm trying to open 1 of 2 possible windows on start. Program decide which window will open on screen dimensions.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "vincellform.h"
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QDesktopWidget mydesk;

if (mydesk.screenGeometry().width() == 800 && mydesk.screenGeometry().height() == 480)
{
    VincellForm vf;
    vf.show();
}
else
{
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
}

return a.exec();
}
```

I think that this code is correct, but it isn't. If I'm on different screen (1280*1024 I think) program goes to else part (MainWindow w; w.show();) and then goes to return, but no window is opened. But if I changed a code to:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "vincellform.h"
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QDesktopWidget mydesk;

if (mydesk.screenGeometry().width() == 800 && mydesk.screenGeometry().height() == 480)
{
    VincellForm vf;
    vf.show();
}

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();


return a.exec();
}
```

it runs perfectly (MainWindow will open after return). I can't even imagine where the problem can be... Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining the window variables locally in the `if` and `else` blocks. This means the windows are destroyed immediately after they're shown.

You have two solutions. If you don't mind creating both windows, but only showing one, do this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDesktopWidget mydesk;

    VincellForm vf;
    MainWindow w;

    if (mydesk.screenGeometry().width() == 800 && mydesk.screenGeometry().height() == 480)
    {
        vf.show();
    }
    else
    {
        w.show();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

If you only want one of them created, you'll have to resort to dynamic allocation:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDesktopWidget mydesk;

    std::unique_ptr<VincellForm> vf;
    std::unique_ptr<MainWindow> w;

    if (mydesk.screenGeometry().width() == 800 && mydesk.screenGeometry().height() == 480)
    {
        vf.reset(new VincellForm);
        vf->show();
    }
    else
    {
        w.reset(new MainWindow);
        w->show();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Note: `std::unique_ptr` comes from C++11. If you don't have this yet, use raw pointers instead a `delete` manually at program end.

Comment: You don't need raw pointers, Qt comes with a number of auto pointers. [QPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qpointer.html) is the most appropriate in this case.

Comment: How about `std::unique_ptr<QWindow>w = (screenGeometryTest ? new VincellForm() : new MainWindow);` ? They share a base class, after all.

Comment: @RobbieE No, `QPointer` is not what you need here. Quoting the destructor docs from the link you posted: "Just like a normal pointer, destroying a guarded pointer does *not* destroy the object being pointed to."